# react-codemirror2 has no CSS effect

Tags: reactjs, codemirror, react-codemirror

I added [react-codemirror2](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2) to my project but it does not load the css although I import the `codemirror.css` file, because it is mentioned that css should be applied into the component somehow ([mentioned here](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2#requiring-codemirror-resources)), but long story short it is still rendered like this:
[Code Mirror with no CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42nPC.png)

I really don't know what the issue can be. So here is my code:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/theme/material.css';
import { Controlled as CodeMirror } from 'react-codemirror2';
require('codemirror/mode/xml/xml');
require('codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript');

class MyComponent extends Component {
  handleValueChange = value => this.props.onUpdateValue({ value });
  render() {
const { shade } = this.props;
const myOptions = {
      mode: 'xml',
      theme: shade === 'dark' ? 'material' : 'default',
      lineNumbers: true,
    }
return (
  <CodeMirror
    id="editor"
    value={this.props.value}
    options={myOptions}
    onBeforeChange={(editor, data, value) => {
      this.handleValueChange(value);
    }}
    onChange={(editor, data, value) => {}}
  />
);
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    shade: state.muiTheme.shade,
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(MyComponent);
```

I also tried to `@import` the css file inside the `global.css` file of my project (like below) but nothing's changed.

```
@import '/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
@import '/node_modules/codemirror/theme/material.css';
```

I really don't know what else should be tried or what am I doing wrong, because it shouldn't be something very special. So I'm asking you, and any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this is something which may only happened to me but I post my solution, maybe someday someone have same issue. 
As I said the problem was not loading the css, I don't know how others handle this issue but I have to copy all styles inside the `node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css` into a new `css` file and put it in some path inside my project. And inside the `global.css` file of my project I just imported that new created file like `@import absolute/path/to/file/codemirror.css;` and it worked at least for one case and one theme. I'm sure there is better ways to connect to all `css` files of `codemirror` but for now it did the basic thing that I needed.

Comment: I solved the problem in the same way back in the days.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you met the problem, but it works for me.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

// Import the code mirror component.
import { Controlled as CodeMirror } from "react-codemirror2";

// The following two imports is for the theme.
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/theme/material.css';

// This import is for the language syntax highlighting.
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       src: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    let option = {
      mode: 'javascript',
      theme: 'material'
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Controlled
          value={this.state.src}
          option={option}
          onBeforeChange={(editor, data, value) => {
            this.setState({ src: value });
          }}
          onChange={(editor, data, value) => {}}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

Maybe the problem is here:

```
const myOptions = {
  mode: 'xml',
  theme: shade === 'dark' ? 'material' : 'default',
  lineNumbers: true,
}
```

You should set the option object in rendering function before `return`, or set it in `constructor()` and attach it to `this`, like `this.option = {}`.

Comment: Note that `require('....css');` will result in a slightly different style. The font size is 0.8em instead of 1em. Obviously, this could also be changed in the stylesheet, but I think it's worth mentioning.